# Database design for one key with multiple values

Tags: database-design

In my application, users are able to create lists. Each list contains infinite records. Each record contains one key and this key, may contain zero or infinite values.

To clarify consider this:

**List title**: "Greeting in some languages"

**List records:** (Below table is a simple UI design (HTML form) that user has filled)

```
| Hello         | Hallo        | Ciao        |
| Bye           | Tschüss      | arrivederci | ... | ... | ... |
| Good morning  | Guten Morgen | Buongiorno  |
| Good night    | Gute Nacht   | Buonanotte  | ... |
|[Another key]  | [Value 1]    | [Value 2]   |
```

First column always contains keys. Next columns are values for the first column.

The approach that came to my mind is:

1. Use a NoSQL database (e.g., MongoDB).
2. Create a table called `lists` which contains two columns: `id` `title` (in this example "Greeting in some languages").
3. Create a table called `lists_contents` which contains three columns: `list_id`, `key`, `values`

In the `lists_table` I would like to store all values which belong to the key, in the `values` column as sub-record.

So this is a record (in above list) which is going to insert:

```
{
    list_id: 123,
    key: "Hello",
    values: ["Hallo","Ciao","Salam","..."]
}
```

Another approach is to create an independent table for `values` column.

What is your idea?
Is  using a NoSQL database a good tool or a relational database? Are my approaches suitable?

Comment: what queries, apart from insertion, are going to be used?

Comment: @danblack : Users may edit or delete records or delete whole list. Clients may search for list titles. I think the main query is `selection`.

Comment: *In my application, users* USERS table *are able to create lists* LISTS table, N:1 to USERS *Each list contains infinite records* RECORDS table, N:1 to LISTS *Each record contains one key* KEY is attribute of RECORD, stored in RECORDS table. *key, may contain zero or infinite values.* VALUES table, N:1 to RECORDS

Comment: *"Each list contains **infinite** records. Each record contains one key and this key, may contain zero or **infinite** values."* I get the feeling that you say *"infinite"* but you mean *"arbitrarily large number of"*

Comment: Thanks @Akina. My main issue is to separate `values` table (which is more clear and more readable) or keep them as a column in `lists_contents` table. Which is better at performance.

Comment: *or keep them as a column in lists_contents table* CSV field? this does not meet the requirements of normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in relational databases, storing arrays in a column violates 1NF.  Because the array elements all relate only to the key, and not each other, so they should be separate and atomic.

So in the relational model you would have:

List Main Table:
id, title

```
1 | Hello
2 | Bye
3 | Good morning
4 | Good night
```

List Contents Table:
id, main_id (FK), title

```
1 | 1 | Hallo
2 | 1 | Ciao
3 | 2 | Tschüss
4 | 2 | arrivederci
5 | 3 | Guten Morgen
6 | 3 | Buongiorno
7 | 4 | Gute Nacht
8 | 4 | Buonanotte
```

If ordering is required, then an ordering mechanism or column should be added to the list contents table.

These tables could potentially actually be the same table with some changes to the primary key, an element type column and a foreign key from the table onto itself.

That's the typical canonical relational design for this.  Then when selecting the data, you would perform an appropriate pivoting operation to present the data.

The reason for the atomicity and the design of the relations of the list content items to their key is that a single update to a single list content item would only require a single row to be updated.

This is the foundation for the motivation of the relational model and the normal forms.

In a non-relational database, the entirety of the array might be treated as a document or data structure as you discuss, and the nature of the updates of such data are obviously not subject to the motivations of the relational model.

Comment: Thanks. Which database do you suggest for this application? Relational or Non-relational? I am going to use MongoDB

Comment: @AliN11 without knowing more about your complete system, it would be hard to say.  I would typically use a relational database because normalization and data modeling to me is very natural in that area.  For most systems, that is sufficient.  There are some advantages to other less-relational models in certain scenarios.  Specifically, I have also used star schemas because in data warehousing they have advantages.  It really depends on your problem, but I will say that the vast majority of structured real-world data is simply best modeled in the normalized relational model.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the dynamic number of columns (1 for each new language), I expect it would easier to manage this in the form of two related tables: 1. with your key and potentially one or more properties (to which new rows can be added for each new word) and 2. a table with translations for each key in table 1.

I have recently reviewed some strategies on this and found the below linked answer to be most useful, which expands on what I note above.

The answer provided a sample table:

```
    CREATE TABLE T_PRODUCT (pr_id int, PRICE NUMBER(18, 2))
    CREATE TABLE T_PRODUCT_tr (pr_id INT FK, languagecode varchar, pr_name text, pr_descr text)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/323365/10340388

Comment: Thanks but I think this is not related to my question. The language example was an example. It can be everything else which could be listed

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the problem.  However I don't feel the database design proposed would be different just because the content would be something different than language.  Having two tables just seems to make sense in this situation.  See also Cade Roux' (much more sophisticated) answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217194/160347